# can you use swift actions as a second attempt at an action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Can you use a swift action (I.e. travel devotion) as a save from falling to make a second attempt to grab a rope, etc., for example?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Travel Devotion and actions taken as a move? Right now this is really broad/vague/unclear, and can’t really be answered.

Comment: @KRyan Given the title and the question proper, this seems answerable enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A creature can only take a swift action if it possesses a special ability that enables it to take a swift action

Unlike, for example, free actions, full round actions, move actions, and standard actions, a creature's ability to take swift actions depends on the special abilities the creature possesses. For instance, a creature *can't* opt to take a swift action to move up to its speed or to take a swift action to cast a spell unless the creature also has a special ability to take a swift action to move up to its speed or has a special ability to take a swift action to cast a spell, respectively. (In the latter case, that can include knowing or having prepared a spell with a casting time of 1 swift action.)

So, while all creatures typically *get* a swift action every turn (unless they've previously used their swift action for an immediate action), not all creatures can *use* that swift action.

#### Other Stuff

- To catch oneself while falling, one makes a [Climb](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/skillsAll.html#climb) skill check (*either* DC = 20 + the wall's Climb DC for a wall (so, in other words, usually impossible) *or* DC = 10 + the [slope](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#table-mountain-terrain-features)'s Climb DC for a slope (which is, then, usually DC 10)). I am unaware of any special ability allowing a creature a second attempt to catch itself while falling.
- The feat Travel Devotion (*Complete Champion* 62-3), while the special ability lasts, *only* enables the creature to use its swift action to move up to its speed. The benefit does *not*, for example, enable the creature to take an additional move action.

Comment: @Miniman Fortunately, following the link to the Climb skill says what kind of action it is: "Catching yourself or another falling character doesn’t take an action." I can include that anyway if you want, though.

Comment: @Miniman The Climb skill lacks a Try Again entry, so "If this paragraph is omitted, the skill can be retried without any inherent penalty, other
than the additional time required" (*PH* 66), but getting the *opportunity* to make the Climb check to catch yourself requires having taken the time to make the *initial* Climb check, so probably no catching yourself more than once (unless a generous DM allows another attempt during a long fall).

Comment: That seems like good information to add to the answer!